# WCF Restfull service : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am Working on WCF service, Its working well on My local side.

I Hosted on Server, this is showing error when i calling the service

(Null Reference Error ) Object reference not set to an instance of an object, when calling a WCF service

I found same issue here http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1986

I follow this but still have same issue.

Comment: Which line gives you error.

Comment: when i try to open my .svc file Example : http://test4.XXXXXX.com/WCFServices/XXXXXXXX.svc

Comment: Any errors in the event log? I understand you can't browse to the service. You could try connecting to the service with WCFTestClient.